# Dropbox crashes nautilus

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, dropbox

I updated to Oneric Ocelot finally, and decided to make the leap to Unity, but Dropbox is choking Nautilus.

When I log in to 3D, I get a message saying that Nautilus needs to be restarted in order for Dropbox to function properly, but clicking the "Restart Nautilus" button does nothing. I can close the alert but Nautilus doesn't seem to be running.

When I log in to Unity 2D (not even sure what that is) Nautilus seems to load but if I try to open the Dropbox directory it chokes.

I can't launch Nautilus manually in Unity 3D (i get a "segmentation fault" error), though I can in 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subsequent updates seem to have resolved the issue.